# Find a Range of values and use starts with xsl

Tags: xslt, range, between

I need to ask if Range of `Supplier_ID` between 985000 and 989999 then set in tag `AllocationNumber`  the value 'FX' else let it empty.

I thought to solve it with the starts with xsl function.

But it does not work (I'm new in XSL)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:user="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/user" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="user xs fn  user">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Form">
        <MaxPostInvoice>
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">C:\Program Files (x86)\MaxPostInvoice-v1.18.xsd</xsl:attribute>
            <Header>
                <VendorID>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Fields">
                        <xsl:for-each select="Supplier_ID">
                            <xsl:for-each select="@source">
                                <xsl:attribute name="source"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Fields">
                        <xsl:for-each select="Supplier_ID">
                            <xsl:for-each select="@confidence">
                                <xsl:attribute name="confidence"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Fields">
                        <xsl:for-each select="Supplier_ID">
                            <xsl:for-each select="@rawContents">
                                <xsl:attribute name="rawValue"><xsl:if test="//Fields/Supplier_ID[@rawContents = '']"><xsl:value-of select="''"/></xsl:if><xsl:if test="//Fields/Supplier_ID[@rawContents != 'X']"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:if></xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Fields">
                        <xsl:for-each select="Supplier_ID">
                            <xsl:for-each select="@contents">
                                <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:if test="//Fields/Supplier_ID[@contents = 'X']"><xsl:value-of select="''"/></xsl:if><xsl:if test="//Fields/Supplier_ID[@contents != 'X']"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:if></xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </VendorID>
                <AllocationNumber>
                    <xsl:attribute name="rawValue">
                        <xsl:if test="number(./Fields/Supplier_ID/@contents) &gt;= 985000 and number(./Fields/Supplier_ID/@contents) &lt;= 989999">
                            <xsl:value-of select="FX"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:if test="number(./Fields/Supplier_ID/@contents) &gt;= 985000 and number(./Fields/Supplier_ID/@contents) &lt;= 989999">
                            <xsl:value-of select="FX"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </AllocationNumber>
            </Header>
        </MaxPostInvoice>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the input XML:

```
<Form name="FP0001">
    <Fields>
        <Supplier_ID contents="985000" rawContents="" source="OCR" confidence="100"/>
        <Supplier_Name contents="Leifheitstr" rawContents="" source="OCR" confidence="100"/>
        <Supplier_Street contents="abcde" rawContents="" source="OCR" confidence="100"/>
    </Fields>
</Form>
```

Result
`<Header>
    <VendorID source="OCR" confidence="100" rawValue="" value="985000 " />
    <AllocationNumber rawValue="" />
  </Header>`

Comment: It depends on the context of the node you are in. Can you show your input XML file? and a more detailed xsl, is it a template match?

Comment: Also take into account that testing for the first digits is not the same as checking if the number is inside the range.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead. Also post a **complete** stylesheet. It doesn't have to be your *entire* stylesheet, but it should be *complete* in the sense that we can run it directly and see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided a input XML, if your XPath is correct, you could do:

```
<xsl:attribute name="rawValue">
    <xsl:if test="number(./Fields/Supplier_ID/@contents) &gt;= 985000 and number(./Fields/Supplier_ID/@contents) &lt;= 989999">
        <xsl:value-of select="FX"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="rawValue">
    <xsl:if test="number(./Fields/Supplier_ID/@contents) &gt;= 985000 and number(./Fields/Supplier_ID/@contents) &lt;= 989999">
        <xsl:value-of select="FX"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:attribute>
```

If it not works share your input XML and more of your XSLT (complete).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have the same attribute twice? In any case, you need to change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="FX"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="'FX'"/>
```

---

BTW, it seems to me you could simplify this thing significantly to something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/Form/Fields">
    <MaxPostInvoice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\Program Files (x86)\MaxPostInvoice-v1.18.xsd">
            <Header>
                <VendorID source="{Supplier_ID/@source}" confidence="{Supplier_ID/@confidence}" >
                    <xsl:attribute name="rawValue">
                        <xsl:if test="Supplier_ID/@rawContents != 'X'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Supplier_ID/@rawContents"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:if test="Supplier_ID/@contents != 'X'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Supplier_ID/@contents"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </VendorID>
                <AllocationNumber>
                    <xsl:attribute name="rawValue">
                        <xsl:if test="number(Supplier_ID/@contents) &gt;= 985000 and number(Supplier_ID/@contents) &lt;= 989999">
                            <xsl:value-of select="'FX'"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </AllocationNumber>
            </Header>
     </MaxPostInvoice>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: one of them schold be value

Comment: @user3702725 If it works, please close this question by accepting the answer.